# Angular how to call service in base Class method, if its the right approach?

Tags: angular, http, inheritance, service

I am working on a application where I have a base class query.ts and I have a async function that makes the API call in the query method. On the Instance of query I have set up methods like generate body(), header() where I further append the data to table component after getting the response and converting it.

Query.ts

```
interface Class<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function newInstance<T>(TheClass: Class<T>, ...args: any[]): T {
  return new TheClass(...args);
}

export class Query {
  query: QueryType;

  constructor(query: QueryType) {
    this.query = query;
    //this.request();
  }
  
  async exec(
    Klass: Class<QueryResultTable | QueryResultFilterDropdown>
  ): Promise<QueryResultTable | QueryResultFilterDropdown> {
    // fetch the external data here (this is just a demonstration, could be any async op)
    const response = await fetch("api.url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.query),
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      //console.log(result);
      return newInstance(Klass, this.query, result);
    } else if (response.status === 404) {
      throw new Error(result.message);
    } else {
      throw new Error("an error occurred");
    }
  }
}
```

In my component I call it like tablecomponent.ts

@Input() payload!: Query;

// I pass in different instance like QueryResultTable / QueryResultFilterDropdown and call methods based on the instance

In my table on ngInit i call

this.payload.exec(QueryResultTable).then () =>  Get value

I want to move my exec() call in a service and use http methods so I can also use the http interceptor i have setup and error handling.

I have a Dataservice a Service created, how can I either implement the service to acess http in my class method or how can I move my exec() method in Data service and use this.dataService.exec() and pass in the instance.

What would be great to inject service in class or to have class method in a service with instance passed.

Comment: how can I call a http method in sertvice instead of using fetch method in my class method.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

1. [Create a service](https://www.vitainbeta.org/2022/01/04/passing-data-with-angular-service/)
2. [Use HttpClient in your service](https://angular.io/guide/http) as shown on angular.io

Example from [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http):

```
configUrl = 'assets/config.json';

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl);
}
```

Comment: How do I call my instance method in service.